# Random string condition in java

Tags: java

I wrote a program that has a constructor called `Word_generator()`. Inside of this constructor, there is an instance variable of type `int` called `count`. When I run the program, and look at the results, I noticed that the program finished even though I see no way for `count` to have increased. The reason that this is bothering me is because `count` is used as part of the conditional check for a `while` loop at the end of the constructor.

For reference, here is the code I am working on:

```
private String[] array = {"hello", "hi", "what is your name"};

private String getRandomCharacter() {
    return array[random(array.length)];
}

private int random(int length) {
    return new Random().nextInt(length);
}

protected Word_generator() {
    boolean running = true;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 200;
    while (running) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            sb.append(getRandomCharacter());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Word-->");
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());


        if (count++ == max) {
            running = false;
            System.out.println("finished");
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Word_generator();

}
```

Comment: What should you need to do?

Comment: how the finished printed and program terminated?

Comment: In the while loop, every time the condition is checked `count++==max `, the count increments. When it reaches the value of max, the program terminates

Comment: Do you need only One result?

Comment: ```i < 1``` do you mean it to be ```i < wordLength``` or something like that?

Comment: is it like count was incremented but as it was not the equality of max that's why it didn't print the finished every time??? is that the case???

Comment: I see now, getRandomCharacter actually give you a random word... men your code is rather messy... could you tell use what you see in the output?

Comment: here i give i<1 so that only one string will be appended

Comment: @Rafi Uddin In that case there is no need for a loop you are executing the loop body exactly once!

Comment: i see randomly hello.... then hi.... then what is your name
actually my program was randomly running when i use count == max then my friend solve that problem but i tried to understand it but couldn't find how the program print finished....as he incremented the count in if condition .....that's my problem how count incremented and print finished after some string....sorry about the code.....actually i am in a little hurry

Answer (score 1):

The value of count is being increased at this line 
**if (count++ == max){...}**
Here, first of all count is checked whether equal to max, if equals then running is set to false and loop is finished; else count is incremented by one.